# Optimizing a replace operation in multiple files in powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote the script below to iterate through files in a directory, then do a replace based on a hash table (which will actually contain 30 key/values, not 4 as shown here). This is a very, very large directory and the files are somewhat large so I want to make sure this is as optimized as possible, but I'm not that proficient in powershell.  Is this is it or do I need to refactor, and if so, what should I do?  Thank you.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp' -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {
    $lookupTable = @{
        'a' = '1'
        'b' = '2'
        'c' = '3'
        'd' = '4'
    }
    $file = $_
    Write-Host "$file"
    (Get-Content -Path $file -Raw) | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_
        $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            if ($line -match $_.Key) {
            $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
            }
        }
    $line
    } | Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

Comment: PowerShell is not very efficient for this kind of work, so don't expect it to be fast. You could loose the `if ($line -match $_.Key)`, because `-replace` won't change anything if it doesn't match

Comment: Declare your `$lookupLable` hashtable outside of the foreach loop; currently it gets re-declared at each iteration.

Comment: Note that there are no lines.  Get-content -raw is passing the whole file at once.  Maybe you can try out different test cases with measure-command.

Comment: micro-optimisation - if your hashtable doesn't contain any regex, the string.IndexOf() method might be slightly faster than "-match". Try "if ($line.IndexOf($_.Key) ) {" instead and time the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some measured test cases (

- a 5000-iterations loop instead of getting multiple files
- a scalar value `"ano, cosi bude jinak"` instead of reading each of them

)

```
$lookupTable = @{
    'a' = '1'
    'b' = '2'
    'c' = '3'
    'd' = '4'
}
'original approach ', ( Measure-Command {
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt 5000; $i++ ) {                 # get-childitem
        $line = "ano, cosi bude jinak"                  # get-content
        $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            if ($line -match $_.Key) {
                $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
            }
        }
        $line
    }
}).TotalSeconds, $line -join "   "

'@mhu: without IF  ', ( Measure-Command {
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt 5000; $i++ ) {
        $line = "ano, cosi bude jinak"
        $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
        }
        $line
    }
}).TotalSeconds, $line  -join "   "

'HashTable -> Array', ( Measure-Command {
    $lookupArrayCount = $lookupTable.Count
    $lookupArray = New-Object 'array[]' $lookupArrayCount
    $j = 0
    $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $lookupArray[$j] = @( $_.Key, $_.Value )
        $j++
    }
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt 5000; $i++ ) {
        $line = "ano, cosi bude jinak"
        for ( $j = 0; $j -lt $lookupArrayCount; $j++ ) {
            $line = $line -replace $lookupArray[$j]
        }
        $line
    }
}).TotalSeconds, $line -join "   "
```

**Output**:

```
D:\PShell\SO\56587351.ps1
```

> ```
> original approach    1,8059152   1no, 3osi 2u4e jin1k
> @mhu: without IF     1,5973162   1no, 3osi 2u4e jin1k
> HashTable -> Array   0,3225432   1no, 3osi 2u4e jin1k
> ```

Comment: you have no idea how much I learned from this singular post.  THANK YOU!!!!